# Did monasteries hold land and collect rent in medieval Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, monastery

In Ken Follett's series of books about the fictional town of Kingsbridge, the monastery essentially acts as lord over the surrounding area. They collect rent on lands they own, hear cases between the town's residents, and perform other duties that the local lord would. Did this actually happen in Europe?

Comment: What did your preliminary research reveal?  ([Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastery) section on Monastic life points out that Monastic income came in part from rents/investments.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I mostly found lists of internal duties of specific monks and descriptions of monastic life.

Comment: @Zenon Yes, I know what you mean. It can sometimes be hard to see the wood for the trees when trying to search online. As a rule though, it's a good idea to let us know what you have found as part of the question. It can help us to give better answers. :)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: Yes, it has happened. It is called feudalism, and yes, the church was part of the game by owning land.

Comment: @Greg I know what feudalism is, I just hadn't found any reliable sources saying the church was "part of the game" as you put it aside from the ownership of land.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, monasteries in the medieval period were in fact powerful lords of feudal estates.

Most bishops and monasteries had large landholdings, which had been granted to them over the years by kings, or great lords. At one stage, the church was the [largest landholder in Europe](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cusRoE1OJvEC&pg=PT590&lpg=PT590&dq=%22monastery%22%20%22largest%20landholder%20in%20europe%22&source=bl&ots=-U-MwZDyk_&sig=st4GG_NzmDdBzXRrMjxy-MSMgr4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeuoHR7P3WAhUMXhoKHcMVDGIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22monastery%22%20%22largest%20landholder%20in%20europe%22&f=false).

The monastery at Luxeuil in Burgundy had [enough land to support 15,000 manors](http://www.veritasseminary.com/wenix/Library/PRINCETON%20SEMINARY%20COLLECTION%20--%20OCR/PRINCETON%20--%20CHURCH%20HISTORY%20--%20OCR/PRINCETON%20--%20CHURCH%20HISTORY%20--%2003/holychristian00john.pdf). Another bishop of St Martin of Tours in France ruled something like 20,000 serfs.

As with any other feudal landlord, the tenants of the monastery would owe rents and duties to their landlord (in addition to the tithes they owed to the church).

Comment: In France (pre-Revolution), the [**First Estate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estates_of_the_realm#First_Estate) "_comprised the entire clergy_".

Comment: @sempaiscuba [Luxeuil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxeuil_Abbey) is in Burgundy.

Comment: One of the reasons Henry VIII of England dissolved the monasteries - he wanted their money!

Comment: @TheHonRose Absolutely, although their role in the 1536 Pilgrimage of Grace was probably the tipping-point in Henry's eyes. ;-)

Comment: Whereabouts in that second book could I find more about Luxeuil?

Comment: @Zenon It's mentioned (with some other examples) on page 187